# How can I adjust data to highstock (Bigdecimal data aren't available on highstock)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a json stuff for highstock but I can't still make the json suit what highstock requires.

### what i make

`[["2018-03-11","0.0003","0.5","0.0003","0.5",5]]`
the code that is making this.

```
 data=[]
 days.each do |day|
   done_prices=sells.where(updated_at:day.to_date.all_day)
   #data<<[date,open,high,low,close,volume]
     data<<[day.to_s,done_prices.order(:updated_at).first.price,done_prices.maximum(:price),done_prices.minimum(:price),
          done_prices.order(:updated_at).last.price,Buy.sum(:amount)+Sell.sum(:amount)]
 end
 render json:data.to_json
```

### what highstock needs

`[[1300060800000,50.45,50.93,50.19,50.51,109113690]]`

### What I have tried

`a_string.gsub("/"","")`
then the value that was processed following the code above became nil.

Comment: How do your string numbers relate to the highstock numbers? For example, how does `0.0003` become `50.45`?

Comment: I meant the array below an example that highstock needs, Absolutely, the number doesn't become so.

Comment: Your question should be: How to convert a string in a floating point number, or am I wrong?

Comment: gsub works if you have something like this `'"mystring"'`

Comment: Actually, the shown number isn't a floating point number but it is a Bigdecimal number. I don't know how the title of my question should be since I'm not a native English speaker....

Comment: ok, so... what are you trying: String to BigDecimal, BigDecimal to String,  BigDecimal to float, BigDecimal to Int ?

Comment: No, What I'm dealing is a price that is based on BTC, so it will never basically be an integer, and you may know highstock chart is a  javascript's library for displaying a chart. So it could be an inexactly number, Thank you for solving.

Comment: You should find a better question title, because it has nothing todo with your problem and my solution.

Comment: yeah, I guess so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look at your wanted result I assume zou want to turn the values into numbers. You should decide for each, if you want to display the strings as Integer or Float.

[Integer](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i) `to_i`

```
'5'.to_i # => 5
```

[Float](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_f) `to_f`

```
"123.45e1".to_f        #=> 1234.5
"45.67 degrees".to_f   #=> 45.67
"thx1138".to_f         #=> 0.0
```